# What Is The Square's Area? (Vector Algebra approach) MindYourDecisions Youtube video

Tags: vectors

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iszucjbTh5I) shows how to find the square's area using a Pythagorean theorem.

[image]

It seems for me that vector algebra and scalar product properties approach should work also, but I still have no result. If we denote given vectors as $\vec a$, $\vec b$ and $\vec c$, such equations arise

$\vec a^2 = 5^2$

$\vec b^2 = 2^2$

$\vec c^2 = 4^2$

which are given and

$(\vec a - \vec b) \cdot (\vec c - \vec b) = 0$

$(\vec a - \vec b)^2 = (\vec c - \vec b)^2,$

which tell that $(\vec a - \vec b)$ and $(\vec c - \vec b)$ are the sides of the square.

Interesting fact: factorization of $(\vec a - \vec b)^2 = (\vec c - \vec b)^2$ implies $(\vec a - \vec c) (\vec a - 2 \vec b + \vec c) = 0 $. This equation tells that a square's diagonals are perpendicular.

The problem is to express $(\vec a - \vec b)^2$ or $(\vec c - \vec b)^2$ in terms of $\vec a^2, \vec b^2, \vec c^2$ which seems to be not so easy, because after expanding multiplications we get three variables ($\vec a \cdot \vec b, \vec a \cdot \vec c, \vec b \cdot \vec c$) and two linear equations which are not enough and possibly something is missing.

I tried to factorize a linear combination of these two equations in form $(\vec a - \vec b) \cdot (\vec c - \vec b) + k (\vec a - 2 \vec b + \vec c)$ using Wolfram Mathematica for $k \in [-100, 100]$, but there were only factorization for $k = 0$ (trivial case).

Is it possible to solve this problem in terms of scalar products or some another vector operations? If yes, provide a relation, please. If not, show the incorrectness.

Comment: As you point out, vector squares are non trivial and I think you would have to write $a,b,c$ in coordinate form and apply the square root distance thing. Essentially this means you still have to use "The Gougu Theorem".

Comment: @cr001 and still this theorem is equivalent to $(a + b)^2 = c^2$ with $ab = 0$, so it seems to me that an interesting solution might be found.